# How to achieve line of best fit instead of a logarithmic

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I attempted to fit a best fit line with my data points using `scipy.optimize.curvefit` function:

```
x = np.array([0,2246,2600,3465,4392])
y = [-0.763,0.052,0.081,0.266,0.179]
yerror = [0.201,0.113,0.139,0.162,0.204]
plt.errorbar(wavelength,A,yerr=B, xerr=None, fmt='o')

def func(x, a, b, c):#the best fit function
    return a + (b * x)**c 

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y)
x_fit = np.linspace(0, np.max(x), 1000) # create curve line of best fit

plt.plot(x_fit, func(x_fit, *popt), "b")
```

My popt value is: `array([-7.63283206e-01,  2.23580046e-04,  2.63164486e-01])`
where the first value `-7.63283206e-01` is the intercept I wish it to show in the graph.

The data points and best fit are plotted [here using code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdoF8.png) and gives a logarithmic curve, but I want the line of best fit to [pass through the y axis like this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMAHV.png) to illustrate a straighter curve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The curve you got with your code looks like a much better fit to your data than the curve you would like to get.

Comment: Your target plot has one more data point, isn't it? At around x=5500

Comment: @foglerit My current line of best fit does not match my expected results of a more linear curve, I'm worried that I will have to apply a simple straight "line of best fit"

Comment: @itaishz Yes it does but my point still stands as to how to achieve such a best fit, I suspect the red points are deemed as outliers but even so I'm not sure how to code it in such way

Comment: @VictorSong if you want a straight line, try to restrict some parameters (probably `c`) or use a different fit function. If you suspect a datapoint is an outlier, do not include it.

Answer (score 0):

"Best fit" means nothing until the criteria of fitting be specified (Least mean square error or least mean square relative error or least mean absolute error or etc.). The "best fit" is different for each one.

Sine there is no criteria of fitting specified, why not choosing the simplest method, without iterative process and without need of guessed initial values of parameters.

The method below, from https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales gives :

[image]

[image]

If you specify a particular criteria of fitting then an iterative method with guessed initial values are required. You can use the above values a,b,c as initial values for a robust and fast convergence.